# Reindexing error in 1.6 (PHP exception in indexer.php)

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, magento, pdo

Recently I upgraded from 1.4.2 to 1.6.2.  Things actually went fairly smoothly, which was relatively surprising.  Until I tried to reindex my store.  Using the GUI backend gives me the typical no help "Cannot Initialize the indexer process" message.  So I tried running indexer.php from the command line (php shell/indexer.php reindexall) which gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)' in /home/shopchau/public_html/stage/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129

Stack trace:
0 /home/shopchau/public_html/stage/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:model=mys...', 'shopchau_stage', 'gr8target', Array)

1 /home/shopchau/public_html/stage/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

2 /home/shopchau/public_html/stage/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(300): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()

3 /home/shopchau/public_html/stage/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()

4 /home/shopchau/public_html/stage/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)

5 /home/shopchau/public_html/stage/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)

in /home/shopchau/public_html/stage/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
```

Now I've tried the various fixes here:  delete the locks, delete cache, fixing file permissions, and running checks to see if my DB is corrupt.  Far as I can tell, everything else is working.  Nothing so far, has helped this issue.

Anyone have any ideas/fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception tells about connection problem. Are you sure MySQL uses `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` socket? Try changing it to `/tmp/mysql.sock`. You can adjust this in your `local.xml`

Comment: Totally not sure at all, actually.  I certainly didn't change it to be that (not that the upgrade didn't).  I'll have to look more about changing that - I don't see anything relevant in local.xml...

Comment: This setting can be set in `host` node